# How to calculate tile coordinates based on location and crs for arcgis maps

Tags: gis, geospatial, arcgis, proj

I am working on a solution to download map tiles based on given location:(latitude, longitude) and zoom level

Followed https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

The key concept is to convert (latitude, longitude) to tile reference, eg. javascript code:

`function long2tileX(lon,zoom) { return (Math.floor((lon+180)/360*Math.pow(2,zoom))); }`

`function lat2tileY(lat,zoom)  { return (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom))); }`

For sample location (63.433772, 10.393456) and zoom level (17) this formulas return (69320, 35421) which is exactly what's needed to get the tile:

https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=topo4&zoom=17&x=69320&y=35421

Now I am struggling to achieve the same with ArcGIS maps.
The following CRS object is supplied:

`{
   "Name":"Geocache Basis",
   "Crs":{
      "Resolutions":[
         21674.7100160867,
         10837.355008043351,
         5418.6775040216753,
         2709.3387520108377,
         1354.6693760054188,
         677.33468800270941,
         338.66734400135471,
         169.33367200067735,
         84.666836000338677,
         42.333418000169338,
         21.166709000084669,
         10.583354500042335,
         5.2916772500211673,
         2.6458386250105836,
         1.3229193125052918,
         0.66145965625264591,
         0.33072982812632296,
         0.16536491406316148
      ],
      "OriginX":-2500000.0,
      "OriginY":9045984.0,
      "Srid":"EPSG:32633",
      "Definition":"+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
   },
   "Attribution":"Kartverket, Geovekst og kommuner - Geodata AS",
   "MapProvider":"arcgis"
}`

Tried to use proj4 and define EPSG:32633 with 'Definition' field value, then do a projection, but that didn't get me anywhere close to calculating 
the respective tile coordinates, which I experimentally determined to be (47333, 65439)
https://services.geodataonline.no/arcgis/rest/services/Geocache_UTM33_WGS84/GeocacheBasis/MapServer/tile/17/47333/65439

I'd appreciate any hint on what mathematical formula I can apply to follow the same scenario and get the accurate result.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I am running in the same problem.

Comment: The solution i figured out is to use built-in leaflet methods. If you create new map instance with georefrence (CRS) then you can use `mapInstance.options.crs.latLngToPoint` method to convert lat lon to points. Then using this points you can create bounds also with leaflet's `new  Bounds()` method. Then with these bounds you ccarry on the same way as with OSM